# How do I get the old query-replace up-arrow functionality back?

Tags: query-replace

**the case:**
Let's say I did a query-replace is foo1 with foo2, and now I want to query-replace foo2 with foo1.

**In earlier versions of emacs** *(emacs 24, and every other version I remember)*, each previous entry into `query-replace` could be accessed via the  <kbd>up-arrow</kbd>:

I used to go <kbd>ESC-%</kbd>  (`query-replace`), <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> ** **x1**, it then shows ("foo2"), <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, then <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> **x3** ("foo1"), <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

**In my new Emacs** *(emacs 25)*, <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> gives me the entire previous `query-replace` ("foo1 -> foo2"), instead of each field separately.

So I've got to do a rather convoluted edit which involves:

- putting either foo1 or foo2 onto the clipboard. e.g. put foo1 onto clip board (which involves many keystrokes if foo1 is long and complicated)
- **3 x** <kbd>delete</kbd> (to remove the arrow and spaces),
- <kbd>RETURN</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd>, <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

I've no idea why emacs 25 "improved" `query-replace up-arrow like that, but I find it a pain.

Is there any way to get the old, simpler, query-replace up-arrow functionality?

Comment: Note that you can also (still) use `C-x ESC ESC` to repeat the command, editing the inputs if needed.

Comment: I've found this page http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-emacs-25-1-query-replace-history-is-enhanced.html which points out that the arrow is "intangible" so I can switch the 2 fields around, so a simple ESC-T switches their places if they are single words, which is neat. But I see no simple way to do it for more complicated strings, as far as I can see.

Comment: But, I will grant that this ESC-T is suitable about 90% of the time, so mostly solves my desire to do simple edits quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade to 26.1 you can set `query-replace-from-to-separator` to `nil`

25.1 NEWS:

> *** 'query-replace' history is enhanced.
>   When 'query-replace' reads the FROM string from the minibuffer, typing
>   'M-p' will now show previous replacements as "FROM SEP TO", where FROM
>   and TO are the original text and its replacement, and SEP is an arrow
>   string defined by the new variable 'query-replace-from-to-separator'.
>   To select a prior replacement, type 'M-p' until the desired
>   replacement appears in the minibuffer, and then exit the minibuffer by
>   typing RET.

26.1 NEWS:

> ** Customizable variable 'query-replace-from-to-separator'
>   now doesn't propertize the string value of the separator.
>   Instead, text properties are added by 'query-replace-read-from'.
>   Additionally, the new nil value restores pre-24.5 behavior
>   of not providing replacement pairs via the history.

---

Edit: Cursory testing in 25.3 suggests that you can probably use the definition of [`query-replace-read-from`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/replace.el?id=emacs-26.1#n165) from 26.1 to get the same behaviour.  Just copy it to your init file.

If you copy the definition of [`query-replace-from-to-separator`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/replace.el?id=emacs-26.1#n83) as well, then you'll also get the customize interface with the "Disabled" option; but you can use the following regardless:

```
(setq query-replace-from-to-separator nil)
```